# jqgrid file upload (using editurl) with Spring controller

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to use fileupload using jqgrid. After I searched a couple of examples, I implemented my code just like below. When I submitted the edit using editurl, the error occurred.

The error message from Spring server is

> {exception=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request}
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request.

This is client jsp code.

```
colModel:[
{name:'price', index:'price',  width:100,
align:"center",sorttype:"int",editable:true, edittype:"text"},
{name:'prodDetail', index:'prodDetail', width:150, 
align:"center",sortable:true, editable:true},
{name:'prodName', index:'prodName', align:"center", editable:true, 
edittype:"text"},
{name:'prodNo', key: true, index:'prodNo', align:"center", width:60, 
sorttype:"int", editable:true},
{name:'wareHouseCode', index:"wareHouseCode", align:"center", 
editable:true, edittype:"text"},
{name:'fileUpload', index:"fileUpload", align:"center", 
editable:true,   edittype:'file',  
editoptions: {
    enctype: "multipart/form-data"
    },
    width: 210,
    align: 'center',
    search: false
    },
    ],
    sortable: true,
    sortname: 'prodNo',
    pager:"#pager",
    rowNum:5,
    autowidth:true,
    multiselect: true,
    viewrecords:true,
    editurl: "/product/json/getOperation",
    onclickSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
    console.log("aaa");
    alert("onclickSubmit event called... ")
    if (jqXHRData) {
    //jqXHRData.submit();
     $("#uploadForm").submit();
    }
    },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    mtype       : "POST",
    addParams: {addRowParams: {keys: true}, },
    sortorder: "desc",
    loadonce : true,
    jSonReader : {
    root:"rows",
    page:"page",
    total:"total",
    records:"records",
    repeatitems:true,
    cell:"cell",
    id:"prodNo"
    }
    });

    $("#product_list").jqGrid(
    "navGrid",
    "#pager",
    {search:true, edit:true, add:true, del:true,refresh:true},                   
    {closeAfterEdit: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true},
    {closeAfterAdd: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true},
    {reloadAfterSubmit: true},            
    {closeOnEscape:true} 
    );
    });           
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" ' 
action="/product/json/upload">
<br/> <br/>
<table id="product_list"></table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This java controller code.

```
@RequestMapping( value="json/getOperation", 
    method=RequestMethod.POST,
    produces="text/plain"    
    )

public 
String getOperation(
       @RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file,
        //HttpServletRequest request, 
        MultipartHttpServletRequest request,                          
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @ModelAttribute("screen") Screen screen,                        
        Model   model 
        ) 
        throws Exception{


    System.out.println("start here ===>>");

    Enumeration em = request.getParameterNames();
    List<String> prodList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String oper = "";

    ~~~~~
```

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure you have the right direction. For file upload there are a lot of post including here. I recommend you to [see this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577779/jqgrid-file-upload) and the links provided.